# Linux MATLAB not able to access Windows files through smb drive

Tags: linux, windows, matlab

I am running Linux kernel 2.6.18-371. I have read

http://www.linuxdoc.org/HOWTO/SMB-HOWTO-8.html

and am able to access my windows files from command line using

```
/usr/bin/smbclient -L <serverName> <passWD>
```

However, I am not able to get MATLAB to see the windows folder. Is there a work around? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not Matlab specific. In order for a Linux program to see files in a file system, it has to be mounted. For samba, the mount type is called `cifs`, i.e. you do something like

```
mount //servername/share mount-point/ -t cifs
```

where `mount-point` is the directory where you want to mount the share. You will then be asked for your username and password; or you can provide them via options. In order for this to work you have to have the right package installed, on Debian it is called `cifs-utils`.

For more information, see [`man mount`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) and [`man mount.cifs`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs).